# Has anyone integrated Livefyre comments with EE?

Tags: comments

I'm interested in using the free version of Livefyre comments to replace my EE native module, at least for new content. Anyone had experience with this? I've seen Disqus plugins... Thanks,
Matthew

Comment: I've never used it, but should be fairly simple. Can you post the Livefyre embed script?

Answer (score 1):

No, but since the free version is just an embed script with js and html, all you need to do is add it to your template where you want it to appear on the page.

Here's an example embed code:

```
<!-- START: Livefyre Embed -->
<div id="livefyre-comments"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://zor.livefyre.com/wjs/v3.0/javascripts/livefyre.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    var articleId = fyre.conv.load.makeArticleId(null);
    fyre.conv.load({}, [{
        el: 'livefyre-comments',
        network: "livefyre.com",
        siteId: "######",
        articleId: articleId,
        signed: false,
        collectionMeta: {
            articleId: articleId,
            url: fyre.conv.load.makeCollectionUrl(),
        }
    }], function() {});
}());
</script>
<!-- END: Livefyre Embed -->
```

Comment: Thanks, I have an embed script much like this one and have tested it on an empty template; it works, but I am wondering if the script is content-aware. That is, if a user comments there using a social media login, will the post content be reflected on facebook/twitter/etc.? There's no facility to draw the older comments out of the EE db like in Disqus, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would suspect that the post content would be reflected on Facebook since Livefyre and Facebook are both reading the URL. That's the unifying element.
For a migration process, I'm not sure. You'll have to check their docs or contact them.
Also, this: http://www.wpbeginner.com/opinion/reasons-why-we-switched-away-livefyre/